# Flymake Configuration Error in Ubuntu Emacs (C++ mode)

Tags: c++, emacs, makefile, flymake

I have been trying to set up fly-make on my system. But it hasn't been working.
I have a C++ file called advancedFunctions.cpp and a have a Makefile in the directory where my .cpp file is housed. My Makefile contains this:

```
check-syntax:
    g++ -o nul -S $(CHK_SOURCES)

advancedFunctions:
    g++ -o advancedFunctions advancedFunctions.cpp
```

Whenever I invoke flymake via `M-x flymake`, it give this error: 
`Flymake: Configuration Error has occurred while running (make -s -C ./ CHK_SOURCES=advancedFunctions_flymake.cpp SYNTAX_CHECK_MODE=1 check-syntax). Flymake will be switched off.`

What can I do about this? Hints, please.

Comment: I don't know flymake, but... What happens when you run `make` from the command line? Do you have `advancedFunctions_flymake.cpp`? Can you invoke flymake with a simpler makefile, like `all:\n\t@echo hello`?

Comment: I just solved the problem. It had to do with the flymake settings in emacs. I had to download an external package, `flymake-settings.el`, that contained all the settings I needed to make flymake work. Thanks anyways for attempting to answer.

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer so it can be closed. That way others can see that a question has been answered.

Comment: I am not able to configure flymake for C++. Also, I'm not able to find one flymake-settings.el . Well, for me the status remains the same as described in the question. :(

Comment: Probably this is the flymake-settings mentioned: http://code.google.com/p/dea/source/browse/trunk/my-lisps/flymake-settings.el